# Hive: select previous nth row with minimum value for a column

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have data like this

```
ID  START_DATE STATUS
10  2013-05-29 FREE
10  2013-05-29 PAID
10  2014-05-30 PAID
10  2014-11-29 FREE
10  2014-12-02 PAID
10  2015-09-29 PAID
10  2015-12-02 PAID
10  2016-04-04 PAID
10  2016-04-05 FREE
```

My Output should be only contain rows where status = "FREE". Every time the status is FREE, I need to get the previous minimum date where the Status = "PAID".

```
ID STATUS PREVIOUS_MIN_PAID_START_DATE
10 FREE   NULL
10 FREE   2013-05-29
10 FREE   2014-12-02
```

The `LAG()` function only gives the first previous value, how can I get the previous minimum (nth) value?

```
SELECT
  ID,
  STATUS,
  LAG(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'PAID' THEN  START_DATE, 1)  
     OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY START_DATE) AS previous_paid_start_date
FROM
  TEMP
WHERE
  STATUS = 'FREE'
```

Comment: Desired output is not clear. Why there are only three rows? And start_date column is absent, so it's not clear which output rows corresponds to which input rows.

Comment: I have updated the desired output message. I want to get the previous minimum start date from the consecutive "PAID" statuses prior. Hope some one can help me with this.

Comment: two first records have the same date. Does the order depend on STATUS as well as START_DATE or is it a bug in the example data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you were receiving downvotes, I thought this was a pretty interesting (and well described problem).  Anyways, here is ***a way*** to do this, although I must admit it feels sub-optimal and hacky.

Basically, what you need is an index that creates a group of the "current" `FREE` and all subsequent `PAID` until you reach the next `FREE` (I hope I've understood this correctly).  To illustrate:

```
id  start_date status idx
10  2013-05-29 FREE   0
10  2013-05-29 PAID   1 
10  2014-05-30 PAID   1
10  2014-11-29 FREE   1
10  2014-12-02 PAID   2
10  2015-09-29 PAID   2
10  2015-12-02 PAID   2
10  2016-04-04 PAID   2
10  2016-04-05 FREE   2
```

Then from there you can get the minimum start_date where the status is `PAID` over the window of id and and the newly created index.

**Query**:

```
WITH tmp_table AS (
  SELECT *
    , SUM(flg) OVER (PARTITION BY id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS s
  FROM (
    SELECT *
      , LEAD(CASE WHEN status='FREE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS flg
    FROM database.original_table) x )

SELECT id
  , status
  , prev_date
FROM (
  SELECT t.id, t.status, t.s, b.prev_date
  FROM tmp_table t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT id, s, MIN(start_date) AS prev_date
    FROM tmp_table
    WHERE status='PAID'
    GROUP BY id, s ) b
  ON b.id=t.id AND b.s=t.s ) f
WHERE status='FREE'
```

**Output**:

```
id status prev_date
10 FREE   NULL
10 FREE   2013-05-29
10 FREE   2014-12-02
```

Comment: OMG this is awesome. Your solution totally works. I just tested it out. Thanks a ton!!.